# How to make echo table with two div tag?

Tags: php, html, css, echo

How to make echo for table with div ? Table do not work if I need to do echo.

My proposal with echo (not work):

```
<?php
    echo "<div class="container">
        <div class="main">
           <h2>User info</h2><hr/>
                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="input_form_02_qA_01.php">
                    <label>Name:<span>*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="" required/>
                    <label>Email address:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required/>
                    </label>
                    <br/>
                    <label>Age:<span>*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required/>
                    <label>Sex:<span>*</span></label><br />
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="man" required>Man
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="woman" required>Woman
                    <p>
                    <label>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Go to page 2" />
                    </label>
                </form>
        </div>
    </div>";
 ?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *do not work*

Comment: You're not actually using PHP for anything in this code, so just remove all of the PHP and write the HTML directly and it should work fine.

Comment: @Ravi Sorry for my English. Do not work = does not work ?

Comment: I'm not complaining your english. I'm asking could you pls explain your issue. I was not asking you to correct your grammar.

Comment: @David This is only part of code. But this echo does not work because problem with formatting ("<div class="container">).

Comment: @Ravi My issue is that I have problem with formatting. In html is table shown well. But if I need to do echo under the PHP formatting is disable and I do not why. I thing that I have problem with <div class="container"> and  <div class="main"> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the echo " to echo ' and  at last "; to ';
 ?>
Below code will work

```
<?php
echo '<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
       <h2>User info</h2><hr/>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="input_form_02_qA_01.php">
                <label>Name:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="" required/>
                <label>Email address:
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>Age:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required/>
                <label>Sex:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="man" required>Man
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="woman" required>Woman
                <p>
                <label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Go to page 2" />
                </label>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>';
?>
```

Comment: Just remember when you ever need to parse variable values within the string, you can't use single quotes surrounding this string.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at php's [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [nowdoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc).

> Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped, but the escape codes listed above can still be used.
>   Variables are expanded, but the same care must be taken when
>   expressing complex variables inside a heredoc as with strings.
>
> Nowdocs are to single-quoted strings what heredocs are to
>   double-quoted strings. A nowdoc is specified similarly to a heredoc,
>   but no parsing is done inside a nowdoc. The construct is ideal for
>   embedding PHP code or other large blocks of text without the need for
>   escaping. It shares some features in common with the SGML  construct, in that it declares a block of text which is not for
>   parsing.

heredoc example:

```
echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

gives

> My name is "MyName". I am printing some Foo. Now, I am printing some
>   Bar2. This should print a capital 'A': A

nowdoc example:

```
echo <<<'EOT'
My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
This should not print a capital 'A': \x41
EOT;
```

gives

> My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo. Now, I am printing
>   some {$foo->bar[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)}. This should not print a capital 'A': \x41

or in your case:

```
echo <<<'HTML'
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
       <h2>User info</h2><hr/>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="input_form_02_qA_01.php">
                <label>Name:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="" required/>
                <label>Email address:
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>Age:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required/>
                <label>Sex:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="man" required>Man
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="woman" required>Woman
                <p>
                <label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Go to page 2" />
                </label>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to echo an entire block of code; you might try:

```
<?php echo { ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
       <h2>User info</h2><hr/>
            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="input_form_02_qA_01.php">
                <label>Name:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="text" name="nick" id="nick" placeholder="" required/>
                <label>Email address:
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="" required/>
                </label>
                <br/>
                <label>Age:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="number" name="age" id="age" required/>
                <label>Sex:<span>*</span></label><br />
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="man" required>Man
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="woman" required>Woman
                <p>
                <label>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Go to page 2" />
                </label>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `"<div class="container">` to `"<div class='container'>` same applies to everywhere within the string to `echo`.

Replace *double quote* with *single quote* inside string.

Comment: Double quote replaced by single quote but formatting from css (container and main)  do not work.

Comment: what do you mean by do not work.. could you pls explain your problem

Comment: My issue is that I have problem with formatting. In html is table shown well. But if I need to do echo under the PHP formatting is disable and I do not why. I thing that I have problem with <div class="container"> and <div class="main"> .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

Replace all your double quote(") to single quote(') in between echo statement.

for ex:

```
<?php
    echo "<div class='container'>
    //Your code goes here..
      </div>";
 ?>
```

Or else you can use print statement which is more better in your case.

Comment: You mean instead echo to use print ? I'm beginner so be so kind with my stupid question.

Comment: Don't Worry if you are  beginner.
Simply Do code in proper way.

for ex. 
echo "your text1"."your text2"."your text3";

OR

echo " 'your text1'.'your text2'.'your text3'";

Comment: I thing that much better is replace echo "<div class="container">  to echo '<div class="container"> . Only two steps and code work. I thing that I forget to add in head following <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" /> .

Comment: Yes bro.
you can approve my ans. if it is useful to you. Thank you:)

Comment: If I need to add variables inside to my table how can I do that, please ?

Comment: You can simply use variables like this:
echo "Hello1".var1."Hello2";
here var1 is variable name.

Comment: Actually you could use comma for this. `echo 'Hello1', $var1, 'Hello2';` No need for concatenating. See https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-echo-commas-vs-concatenation/